# Адрес страницы без расширения .html и т.п.

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как делают адрес страницы типа:

- `http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/method`
- `http://htmlbook.ru/html/`

То есть без .html или .php и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант: файлы index (index.html, index.php....) в соответствующих директориях. Это если директорий немного и с mod_rewrite не хочется заморачиваться.

Кстати, это 4444 вопрос про PHP на хэшкоде. Мои поздравления с красивой цифрой.

Comment: @Khvorostin, привет из 90х )

Comment: @stck, а то ж, развлекались, как могли

Answer (score 1):

У вас на php сайт? [ЧПУ своими руками](http://www.yaap.info/page/chpu-svoimi-rukami-php). Или если у вас какой-то движок, то читайте про "название движка" ЧПУ.

Comment: Да сайт на php

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `mod_rewrite`. Почитать можно, например, тут: [краткое руководство по htaccess и mod_rewrite](http://www.seoblog.com.ua/2008/11/04/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-and-mod_rewrite/).

Comment: Работает  файл .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
А кто та знает, а на .html это распространяется

Comment: @Fairlooli, у Вас ко всему приписывается расширение php?